# Unable to Access AccountNumber field in SOQL queries

Tags: soql, error

I am trying to run this query (Select Id,Name,AccountNumber from Account) it is giving results in one of the org but throwing error in another one

This is the error message

```
ERROR at Row:1:Column:16
No such column 'AccountNumber' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to 
use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. 
Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: Have you checked the FLS setting on the field in the other sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check field level security, navigate to `Customize>Account>Fields` then click on Account Number check whether it is set to visible or not.

If the field is unchecked on Visible for the current user profile you will receive the above error.

If the organization is using Person Accounts and you are accessing a PersonAccount record then this field may not be available for the person account record type.